# Is there any way to create partial controllers using c# in WEB API2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create partial controllers in WEBAPI like Partial C# classes.

Is there exist such coding scenario or not?

Please help me.

Comment: why you need to do this?

Comment: There's a problem with you code for sure, partial classes for controllers works just fine, try to put your controllers code here so we can have a better understanding in your situation

Comment: It would help us to help you if we could see your code.

Comment: What exact error you got ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @ravindra. Yes it can be done, but without more information from you about your particular issue there not much we can help you with.

Comment: I just want to separate Controller methods in groups ,at different location(file or folder) in solution. That' it.

Answer (score 3):

Works just like when doing normal partial classes.

ValuesController.cs

```
public partial class ValuesController : ApiController {
    public IHttpActionReault Get() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Extending values controller in another code file...

ValuesController.Post.cs

```
public partial class ValuesController {
    public IHttpActionReault Post() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and so on. This is as basic as it gets when it comes to partial classes.

Comment: Then you need to add a [mcve] of what you have already tried so we can see where you get the problem.

Comment: Does attribute routing affect this scenario?